# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'tobytes'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

As a part of my project, I got an error while I run this python code, can anyone help me by fixing this.

Here's the code,

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Create a tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

# Load an image and create a ImageTk.PhotoImage object
img = Image.open("img0.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

# Display the image in a label widget
label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

# Get the raw data from the ImageTk.PhotoImage object
data = photo.tobytes()
```

And the error shows like this,

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ismail\User interface_3d printer>python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ismail\User interface_3d printer\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    data = photo.tobytes()
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'tobytes'
```

Thank you!

Comment: you got ChatGPT to write you this code, didn't you?

Answer (score 2):

The `PhotoImage` object doesn't have a `tobytes` method. If you want to get the raw bytes from the image, you should use the `tobytes` method on the Image object from the `PIL` library, not on the `PhotoImage` object.

**Example**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()

img = Image.open("img0.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

data = img.tobytes()

# You can now do something with the raw data...
```